# They say in java "every thing is an object". Is that true?

Tags: java, oop

When I type

```
int a = 5;
```

Is `a` an object ?

Can anyone explain to me how in java every thing is an object?

Comment: did you put a dot near "a" ? Did something popped-up?

Comment: Who's "they"? Because "they" are wrong.

Comment: For this java has introduced Wrapper classes.

Comment: Is `a` an object? Well, also, it could be asked, is `5` an object?

Comment: Who says that? Who is 'they'?

Comment: Then throw them out or use them as firewood. They worth nothing.

Comment: Agreed. Today, 2015-05-16, the [main page of a well-known online training site](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/java-objects) unfortunately has these terribly wrong words: "Java is an Object Oriented Programming language. Literally everything is an object, so understanding them is critical to your Java foundational base." As horrible as that may be to those of us that care about such things, it gets to the OP's original question: WHY exactly, to people continue to say this? Clearly it is wrong! Yet human beings do not care, or are just imperfect beings with misinformation in their brains....

Comment: All classes are `Object`, not everything. Primitive types (like `int`, `byte`, `long`, `boolean`) aren't objects, keywords aren't objects.

Classes that doesn't extend anything implicitly extends `Object`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every object is a `java.lang.Object` (NOTE:`java.lang.Object` has no super class. ;) )

However, there are many things which are not Objects.

- primitives and references.
- fields (the fields themselves not the contents)
- local variables and parameters.
- generic classes (that may change in Java 8)
- methods (that will change in Java 8)
- blocks of code (that will change in Java 8)

---

Having a block of code as an object is one of the most exciting features in Java 8.  The following examples will all be Closures and therefore objects.

```
x => x + 1
(x) => x + 1
(int x) => x + 1
(int x, int y) => x + y
(x, y) => x + y
(x, y) => { System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", x, y, x+y); }
() => { System.out.println("I am a Runnable"); }
```

e.g. the block of code here will be passed as a `Runnable` *Object*

```
new Thread(() => { System.out.println("I am a Runnable"); }).start();
```

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/003936.html

Comment: "generic classes" are objects like any other classes. Generics are implemented via erasure at compiler time. The blocks of code are syn. sugar much like anon. classes. Guess, I am no great fan of lambda stuff.

Comment: @bestsss In Java 8 (or 9) you will be able to tell the difference between `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` at runtime, i.e. the type won't be entirely erased.

Comment: hmm I don't think java8 contains anything alike, java9 is probably 2015 so I don't know either. Do you have the JCP for that feature or you mean: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=5098163

Comment: The closest I could find was http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#reified which appears to be mostly discussion rather than stating ti will be implemented.

Comment: JSR308 is just about annotations and they can be used to track the generic type but nothing much. Keeping the "declared" type in the object while possible would require more than a great effort for no apparent benefit - for instance using extra bits in the object header to keep a generic type - however that won't work well b/c a generic type might have 'unlimited' generic type like Class `class X<A extends java.util.List, B extends java.util.Comparator, C extends java.math.BigDecimal, etc, etc>`.

Answer (score 4):

**No**, this is not an Object.Java is not purely Object Oriented Language because of `primitives` and`static`. To make primitive variable as Object java has introduced wrapper classed like [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) etc.

Answer (score 4):

In java you have the primitive types (int, boolean, char, byte...), and everything else extends the `Object` class and therefore is an object.

But the *everything is an object* thing mostly means that you can't have code outside of an object class. You can' make script files for examples, it has to be wrapped in a class.

Answer (score 4):

This is **not** true in java. For example the `int` is actually a primitive. In java everything is an `Object` what extends `Object`. Everything else is **not**.

So, for example you can't manipulate namespaces (packages in java terms) like objects but in Erlang or Clojure you can.

Although java provides an autoboxing feature which can translate primitives to objects. In your case if you say

```
Integer a = 5;
```

java boxes the 5 into the `Integer` reference. If you want to read about autoboxing click here: [autoboxing docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). Objects in java: [Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

If you are looking for a language where **everything** is an object technically, you can try out Common Lisp for example. In Lisp even the `T` (stands for boolean true) is an object.

Answer (score 4):

Although `a` is not an object but a value of a primitive type, Java makes every attempt to hide this fact from you. Starting with Java 5, [primitives are automatically converted to their corresponding object wrappers when necessary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), so that you could store them in containers, pass them to methods requiring objects, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

`a` here is a primitive. Java has both primitives and objects.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything in Java is an object. Some values are of primitive types, to name a few: `int`, `float`, `double`, `byte`, `char`, ... There are ways to wrap these primitive types into Objects (Java can also do this automatically for you).

Now, one could say more accurately, "In java, everything is [defined] in an Object", as a way to highlight that in Java, you cannot define a function or sub that isn't either a class or instance method, like you'd be able to do in `C++` for example.

Answer (score 2):

They are wrong. a is not an Object.

Answer (score 2):

I think this comes from the "early days" when Java was often compared to C, and its structural nature. The statement itself, however, is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything in Java is an Object. There are also the following *primitive* types that can be used within Objects (Definitions taken from the [Oracle Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> - **byte**: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
>     It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).
>     The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays,
>     where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in
>     place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact
>     that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of
>     documentation.
> - **short**: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement
>     integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of
>     32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can
>     use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the
>     memory savings actually matters.
> - **int**: The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It
>     has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of
>     2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, this data type is
>     generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above)
>     to choose something else. This data type will most likely be large
>     enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider
>     range of values, use long instead.
> - **long**: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.
>     It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum
>     value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type
>     when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.
> - **float**: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754
>     floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
>     discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and
>     Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the
>     recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if
>     you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers.
>     This data type should never be used for precise values, such as
>     currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal
>     class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful
>     classes provided by the Java platform.
> - **double**: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754
>     floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
>     discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and
>     Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values,
>     this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above,
>     this data type should never be used for precise values, such as
>     currency.
> - **boolean**: The boolean data type has only two possible values: true and
>     false. Use this data type for simple flags that track true/false
>     conditions. This data type represents one bit of information, but its
>     "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.
> - **char**: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>     a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>     65,535 inclusive).

Most other stuff in Java *is* an object (It inherits from the `Object` class), and the `main()` method is run from an instance of a class. In order to allow primitives to be used in a predominantly object-based system, Java provides wrapper classes that *are* objects representing primitive values (e.g. The `Integer` class represents the same type of data as an `int`). Java also does something called *[autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)* where it automatically wraps a primitive type in its object-wrapper, when, for example, you want to store an `int` in an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Likewise, you can do something like `int x = intArrayList.get(0);` and Java will unbox the `Integer` stored in the Array. Note that these autoboxing operations are not completely free, as they have a performance cost associated with them, so be aware of this if performance really matters to your system.