# What is the difference between List<Object[]> and List<Object>?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

When a method is taking List of Object[] as input, even at the run-time the actual input is List of Object, it is still okay for the method. Question is, for generics in Java, what does `List<something>` really mean and what is the difference between `List<Object[]>` and `List<Object>`?

```java
/*
 * if name is "A", then the input is a List<Object[]>
 * if name is "B", then the input actually is a List<Object>
 */
public List<String> convert(List<Object[]> objectList, String name) {

    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (StringUtils.equals(name, "A")) {
        for (Object[] object : objectList) {
            String code = StringUtils.join((String) object[0], (String) object[1]);
            resultList.add(code);
        }
        return resultList;
    } 

    else if(StringUtils.equals(name, "B")) {
        for (Object object : objectList) {
            String code = (String) object;
            resultList.add(code);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Actually during the run-time, this method works fine and takes both `List<Object[]>` and `List<Object>`.

Just wondering anyone could give some explanation of how this could work.

Comment: An Object could be an Object[], but it could also be an Integer, Cow, horse Object etc.

Comment: Didn't try the code but I think what's bothering is how an Object is accepted in Object[] signature.  Or more precisely in this case, how a value of type List<Object> can pass in a signature of List<Object[]> ?  Shouldn't there be a ClassCastException ?  ( I can of course understand the opposite, that Object[] value is accepted at Object signature because an array is also an Object but here the signature of the method accepts only ListM<Object[]>).

Comment: @Pam Stums I was also feeling confused since I was thinking in the same way. To pass a List<Object> to a method which is expecting List<Object[]> seems unreasonable to me, but when I was debugging I found it actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer in order:

1. **For generics in Java, what does `List<something>` really mean?** The `<>` bracket notation allows you to specify what specific *type* of a *generic class* you want. Basically, a `List` can be a `List<A>`, `List<B>`, etc.: its contents can be anything. Writing `List<Q>` says that it is a `List` which contains things of type `Q`.
2. **What is the difference between `List<Object[]>` and `List<Object>`?** `[]` is the array operator. A `List<Object[]>` is a list containing *arrays of `Object`*. A `List<Object>` is a list containing `Object`s. In Java, [*almost everything*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844012/they-say-in-java-every-thing-is-an-object-is-that-true) is an `Object`, including arrays!

There's another thing to note here: Java generics are complicated (and interesting), and there's a thing called *type erasure* which means that, at run time, `List<Object>` and `List<XYZ>` both become `List` - no specific type! The things in the brackets are only used at compile time - basically, to check that what you've written is correct. See [What does angle brackets T mean in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607550/what-does-t-angle-brackets-mean-in-java) and [Java generics type erasure when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

---

Why does your code run? Well, in the `"A"` case it's straightforward. At runtime, the parameter is just a `List`, but your code expects to find `Object[]`s in that list, and it does. In the `"B"` case it's more complicated: the parameter is just a `List`, and you iterate over its contents *treating them* as `Object`. This is fine because as we said above (almost) everything is an `Object`. You then take **those** objects and cast them to `String` - this is only weird if we don't take into account that at runtime the input `List` is untyped. As far as Java is concerned, there could be anything in that list, and you *tell it* that there are `String`s. Because the input was in fact a list of `String`, it all works out.

The interesting bit (which you didn't include in your code) is how you're calling a method that takes `List<Object[]>` with a `List<String>` without Java complaining at compile time.

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer.
Another question based on what you said: if the method is defined as "convert(List<Object> objectList, String name)" while the actual input is List<Object[]>, then it make sense since array is also an object. But here is the other way around: defined as "convert(List<Object[]> objectList, String name)" but actually takes List<Object>.
Is there any explanation about it?

Comment: Looking at your code, I think all it means is wherever you **call** `convert()` you're avoiding type checking through some mechanism. If you want, you can update your question to show me that code. The reason the code above runs is because of type erasure: at run-time the argument is a `List` - your method is written to handle the typing: In the `"A"` case, it's straightforward: your loop expects `Object[]`, and it finds it. In the `"B"` case, your loop *treats the contents as `Object`* (which is OK), then **casts those contents to `String`** (which is OK to do on an `Object`, not `Object[]`)

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the above

Comment: thanks again for replying.
This method is actually called after I catch the result list returned from JPA: Query.getResultList(). The reason I noticed this scenario is because, sometimes I got a List<Object> by fetching single one column, while other time I got a List<Object[]> by fetching more than one columns.

Comment: What I understand is, it may happens because in the following way: for Query.getResultList() method, it returns List<E> and thus declaring convert(List<Object[]) has no compilation error. At the run-time, JPA will decide what is actually inside of List: whether Object[] or Object, and return it back correspondingly. And because of the type erasure mechanism, whatever returned, unless it is a List, will be allowed to enter into this method, and be processed.