# Storing an array to an object

Tags: java

Is it possible to store an array to an object?

```
Object c = new char[50];
```

I got a question about this on one of my homework assignments.

Comment: Yes. An array is an Object. Try it.

Comment: It takes only a minute or 2 to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every class (including arrays) extend Object, even if not explicitly stated. As such, they are valid objects as expected in OOP.

As far as I'm aware, only primitives (int, char, boolean, etc.) aren't objects in Java, but there are classes that wrap these primitives, which *are* objects (Integer, Character, Boolean, etc.).

See also: [They say in java "every thing is an object". Is that true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11844012/10003008)

Comment: Even a primitive can be a property/field of a class instance. The question was not about OOP but about java (by the tag).