# why there is no issue when anonymous array reference to Object class object

Tags: java, anonymous-arrays

Below expression is having no issue-

```
Object obj = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

but below two have compile time issue-

```
Integer i = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int j = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

why?

Comment: Java motto: everything is an Object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [They say in java "every thing is an object". Is that true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844012/they-say-in-java-every-thing-is-an-object-is-that-true)

Comment: int[] is of type Object but int[] is not of type Integer

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = new int[]{1,2,3}
```

is of type `int[]`, not an integer.

In Java, an array has a superclass of `Object`. Hence assigning that array to an `Object` [is correct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) (if practically useless)

Comment: Hi @brain Agnew, thanks for your reply, but I am still not clear. for code.  Number n = new Integer[] {1,2,3}; Number is the parent class but object n is still not able to hold the Integer array and asks to declare array of Number(i.e. Number[] n) instead of Number.

Comment: A Number is *not* an array of Numbers. Your array contains a collection (not a Java collection, to be clear with my terminology). Integer j could be of the value 1 OR 2  OR 3. But an array could have *all* those values, and to get an individual number you have to decide which one you want